# Use selenium to enter and submit form in python

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get("url.com")

logForm = driver.find_element_by_name("user_login").send_keys("xx") 
passForm = driver.find_element_by_name("user_pass").send_keys("yy")
driver.find_element_by_id("logSubmit").click()
```

However, this returns invalid login, even when my credentials are correct

Here's the source code for the form:

```
<div id="loginForm">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input class="txt" type="email" name="user_login" tabindex="1" value="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input class="txt" type="password" name="user_pass" tabindex="2">
            </li>
            <li class="submit">
                <a id="a-fgt" class="sub" href="#" tabindex="4">Forgot Password</a>
                <input type="submit" id="logSubmit" value="Login" tabindex="3" />
                <div id="rightBlock">
                    <span id="respMsg"></span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: **invalid login** solely depends on the validity of the credentials you have passed in-terms of `username` and `password`. Check if `send_keys()` is properly sending the desired characters or not

Comment: what is the best way to check this? I know if I use the same credentials on the webpage it works, so I'm wondering if send_keys is maybe not entering the text as it should be.

Comment: can u share url for more info

Comment: @NBC `send_keys()` for `username` field would fetch you the desired observations. Try to invoke `send_keys()` with the text for `password` field within `username` field to validate if all is well with `send_keys()`

Comment: @NBC Consider updating the question with the versioning details of the binaries you are using along with the _error stack trace_.

Comment: check if its on frame or label

Comment: Firstly make sure your script can run pass on non-headless browser which can help to watch the running process and debug to see the entered username & password is correct or not.  Then switch to headless browser, like you used PhantomJS

Comment: Add a long sleep before click submit, when run into the sleep, exit the execution in cmd window to keep the browser opening, then open browser DevTool and read the entered username & password through javascript in `Console` Tab of DevTool.  To check they are correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try Sending an enter key along with the password. Though not a good practice, this would solve these scenario's many times.

*please be aware whether you are sending valid/corrcet ID & password.

```
driver.find_element_by_name("user_login").send_keys("xx") 
driver.find_element_by_name("user_pass").send_keys("yy\n")
```

Hope it helps !
Happy Coding :)

Comment: You're using nearly the same code as OP already tried. Share some comments about how your approach can solve the issue